# How to check if there's no change in a database?

Tags: java, database, junit, entitymanager

I have a short question about `EntityManager`. 
I have a method `updateAdmin(Admin a)`.
Behaviour:
This method should update an existing Admin in my database.
Return true if an admin exist an the update was successful.
Return false if the Admin that has to be updated does not exist in the database.

Now I want to write a JUnit test method.
I can check that the `updateAdmin(Admin a)` method returns a `true` if the Admin is already in the database and the update was successful.

I also can check that the method returns `false` if the `Admin` does not exist.
But how can I check that the database was not changed and the update was not successful??

Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: have to tried `mysqli::begin_transaction ([ int $flags [, string $name ]] )`

Comment: I would assume you get an exception when the database update statement blows up. You can test that right now by for example leaving a property which is not-nullable as null.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `find()`-ing the admin at first. If it doesn't exist already return false or perform a `merge()` and return true. Assuming you are using JPA `EntityManager` this should work

```
public boolean updateAdmin(Admin a) {
    Admin existingAdmin = entityManager.find(a.getId(), Admin.class);
    if (existingAdmin == null) {
        return false;
    }

    em.merge(a);

    return true;
}
```